# My process needs to read a file passed from the stream in order to save space (LINUX)

Tags: linux, perl

I need to do this:

1. unpack a file.7z
2. read the unpacked file and pass it to a perl process without writing it to disk

like this:

$unpack file.7z | perl_process > out_file

the process needs to read the unpacked file from the stream because it is very large and I need to save space.

currently I have (but can't do) this:

1. unpack file.7z (generates in_file that is extremely large)
2. process in_file out_file (the process reads in_file and generates out_file)

Can you give me ideas of how could I achieve what I need?

Comment: What are you using to unpack?

Comment: Look at [man 7z](http://linux.die.net/man/1/7z).  It sounds like you want something like`7z x  myfile -so | myscript.pl > out_file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So each archive contains exactly one file?

The `7z` command-line program has an `-so` option that makes it send the unpacked output to STDOUT. That means you can send it through a pipe to your perl process:

```
$ 7z e archive.zip -so | perl program.pl
```

Or you could use `open` to get the unpacked information within the perl program:

```
my $archive_file = 'archive.zip';

open my $archive_fh, '-|', "7z e $archive_file -so";

while ( <$archive_fh> ) {
    # Process text line
}
```

If you don't already have a command-line version of 7zip then you should download `p7zip` which is [described here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/P7zip?cm_mc_uid=61758477837914607855154&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1460785515)

Comment: @polettix: Thank for the edit. It was a shambles wasn't it!

Comment: ahahah now I know one more English word - shambles! Actually it wasn't, it's easy to miss a "context switch" between Markdown and code.